# exclusion of two different querysets

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a GK test interface with django. In this, the questions once submitted to a user should not appear again. 
This table stores all the questions once submitted, and all other data related to that.

```
class UserLog(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(to = UserTestSession, default = None)
    question = models.OneToOneField(to = MCQuestion)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to = User)
    selected_option = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    answer_status = models.BooleanField(default = True)     
    quest_submit_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    ans_submit_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True,null=True)
    def getDiff(self):
        diff = self.quest_submit_time - self.ans_submit_time
        return divmod(diff.days * 86400 + diff.seconds, 60)
    time_elapsed = property(getDiff)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " " + str(self.question)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('question','user',)

class MCQuestion(models.Model):
      question = models.CharField(max_length = 1000,unique = True)
      optA = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
      optB = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
      optC = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
      optD = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
      right = models.IntegerField(default=1,validators=(MaxValueValidator(4),MinValueValidator(1)))
      category = models.ForeignKey(to = Category,default=None)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.question) + " ~ category : " + str(self.category)
```

I tried this line to exclude.

```
all_questions = MCQuestion.objects.filter(category = cat.category_id)
submitted_questions = UserLog.objects.filter(user = request.user).values('question_id')
unsubmitted_questions = list(all_questions.exclude(question__in = submitted_questions))
```

Even if these lines are included in my views.py the questions are repeated in the front end . I think the exclude() not works properly.

Comment: What is your question? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: what is submitted_questions?

Comment: Sorry . it doesn't work.That is my problem.Even if I used the exclude() function, the same questions are appearing again

Comment: i have edited my question. Please check it and help me

Comment: can you print the submitted_questions and share the count of result set?

Comment: Yes. Here it is:                 <QuerySet [<UserLog: ccc Which consists of two plates separated by a dielectric and can store a charge? ~ category : General Knowledge>, <UserLog: ccc Where is the headquarters of Intel located? ~ category : General Knowledge>, <UserLog: ccc What does AM mean? ~ category : General Knowledge>, <UserLog: ccc RAM stands for ~ category : General Knowledge>, <UserLog: ccc Google is a: ~ category : General Knowledge>, <UserLog: ccc  'OS' computer abbreviation usually means ? ~ category : General Knowledge>]>
6

Answer (score 0):

One line query for that would be

`MCQuestion.objects.exclude(userlog__user__isnull=False)`

This would give you all the MCQuestions which are not submitted to any user.

Comment: Actually the questions are submitted to the users not by the users

Comment: I have edited the answer. Does this solve your prolem?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: According to my understanding, you are storing userlog object for every question answered by user and each question is given to only one user. Now, you want to show the question to the user and want to make sure that the question is visible only once and it should not be answered by the user. 
Am i correct?

Comment: There is one mistake. Actually the questions are general for all the users, but for a user each question will be given only once.Hope its clear